# High consumption RAM after publish WPF application on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-server-2012-r2

I have problem with my WPF application. My application displays chart and photo.

- Char render from database and for this I use Nation Iinstrument
  components for WPF (Graph) ([NI](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/14071/en/))
- Displayed pictures is jpg and I use it for that image (WPF controls) - read from file

The application displays new data every 30 - 40 seconds

When I check application on developer computer RAM is on the level 280 MB (no matter if application is debug or release)

After publish to Windows Server 2012 R2 after a few cycles (10-15) RAM is on level 750-800MB and it kills my application

For check why it's happening on server I installed CLRProfiler4, and I saw most of the RAM is taken by `Threading.Dispatcher` and `Generic.List` , but the problem absent on local machine.

drop form Profiler:
[image]

how to diagnose it better?

Comment: Just use the profiler in visual studio?

Comment: But local machne (developer pc) everything is OK. On VS profiler perfect to see when start GC and RAM falls. I can not install on the server VS

Comment: Deploy the debug pdb files and debug remotely?

Comment: if you have on mind Remote debugger it's impossible because I have access to the server only with the help of VPN and two remote desktops...
Is it possible that GC does not start on the server? Here is something on the subject
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165011%28v=office.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
but for .net 1.1

Comment: How to change max memory limit for application? Additional information my app is 32bit

Comment: That documentation is old. GC is always on.